# Can c++ 'pass by reference if possible'?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I have a method with a parameter that is read-only.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T t) {...}
```

This definition has the benefit that `foo(2)` is syntactically correct. However, it has the downside that applying `foo` on a big object makes it copy the object. Since I only read from the argument, this is just a waste of time and memory.

The standard solution is to make the parameter `t` a const reference. However, this has the downside that `foo(2)` is not syntactically correct anymore. I would have to do `int i = 2; foo(i);` which I find unfortunate.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds? So such that `foo(2)` is syntactically correct and applying `foo` on an object makes it pass by reference?

EDIT: Apparently a const reference is already the best of both worlds. Now I would like to know why this is. Why is `foo(2)` syntactically correct? How can `2` become a reference here?

Comment: For starters, `foo(2)` should compile perfectly well, if the template parameter is a `const` reference, you're mistaken. But, in any case, what you're looking for is called a "forwarding reference". Your C++ book should have a chapter in the advanced topics section that describes how to use forwarding references.

Comment: `foo(2)` would still be totally fine. `int 2; foo(2);` is wrong no matter how `foo` takes arguments.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I don't see any reason to use a forwarding reference here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Wow, you're right! Now this makes little sense to me. Why don't you need an instance to pass by reference if the parameter is a const reference?

Comment: @user2357112 You're right lol, I don't know what I was thinking with that code, fixed it in the OP.

Comment: A temporary object of type `int` is created, initialized with the value `2`, and bound to the reference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do you also happen to know why this is only done with const references and not with regular references?

Comment: The language doesn't allow binding temporaries to non-const references. As I understand, the motivation was to avoid surprises like this: `void f(long& x} { x = 42; } int y = 0; f(y);` (hypothetical, doesn't compile; but if it did compile, `y` would still be zero).

Comment: `2` binds to a const reference because the language definition says so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ will materialize temporaries when needed, and you can bind a temporary to a `const&`, but not a `&`.

So `foo_value(2)` creates an `int` with value `2` called `t` as a parameter.  `foo_cref(2)` creates an anonymous temporary, then binds the `int const& t` parameter to it, where `foo_value` and `foo_cref` are the obvious variants of `foo` you talk about in the question.